# I'm am trying to change a css property using $_GET but am not getting results

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

First of all this is a wordpress page so [insert_php] is a replacement for `<?php`.

The url of the page is as follows "http://********.com/?page_id=98#highlights?sel=q1s"

the code on the page is as follows

```
<div id="Question1" style="background-color:[insert_php] if ($_GET['sel'] == "q1s") { return "black"; } else { return "white"; };">
```

I'm sure I'm overlooking something here.

EDIT :

```
<div id="Question1" style="background-color:[insert_php] if ($_GET['sel'] == "q1s") { echo "black"; } else { echo "white"; }[/insert_php];">
```

this is my current code and it still showing no results, I checked the actual value I'm getting for background-color and for some reason am getting the result "white".

Comment: you want `echo` not `return` this is not a function

Comment: Maybe a typo but you use a "?" in the url before sel=q1s and also the "#" might cause a problem. Try : http://**.com/?page_id=98&sel=q1s#highlights

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure but I think the parenthesis is missing around the condition, and also you have to use an `echo`; like this :

```
if ($_GET['sel'] == "q1s") { echo "black"; }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<div id="Question1" style="background-color:<? if ($_GET['sel'] == "q1s") { echo "black"; } else { echo "white"; };">
```

you want echo instead of return

Comment: It should also be noted that the php open tag `<?` is a shorthand and not always available. It is recommended to use `<?php`. Despite that note, there is an additional shorthand that might be useful if you want that would simply it all to `<?=($_GET['sel']=='q1s'?'black':'white')?>`. That shorthand open tag implies the `echo` command and inside is a ternary operator that acts like an simple if statement.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot the closing php tag. Normally ?> but since you are using wordpress use [/insert_php]

Also, you should echo instead of return. You are not in a function.

```
<div id="Question1" style="background-color:[insert_php] if ($_GET['sel'] == "q1s") { echo "black"; } else { echo "white"; }; [/insert_php]">
```